# What will the $result be when MySQL returns nothing?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, long-polling

This might seem ridiculously simple, but I've been getting all kinds of error depending on how I handle a query that returns nothing.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id > ".$messageId;
$result =mysql_query($query);
$time = time();
while(time()-$time<60 && $result==false)
{
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
if(result != false)
     //Encode response
else
     //return nothing
```

How do I check whether my mysql_query() returned anything?

Comment: Looks like you're going to DOS attack your own database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the number of returned rows using [mysql_num_rows().](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Presuming your loop is to query something until it gets a result, it would be

```
while(time()-$time<60 && $num_rows == 0)
{
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

(not sure whether what you're doing here is a really good idea, as it is likely to put a terrible burden on the database server, but that's a different issue)

[mysql_query()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will return `false` only on "real" errors, e.g. a misspelled query or lost connection.

Comment: Also you have to make sure that the MySQL connection didn't time out and that the session is ok. Use mysql_ping for this (although this function can do automatic reconnects, I'd recommend not to use this feature).